# First business analysis document for quote

Tags: requirements, business-analyst, analysis

My client requested me to send them a quote for man/day pricing. Their needs and flows are clear.

What I am planning to do is describing the modules and relations. Then I will put all these outputs in a definitive diagram (beside the quote document).

What kind of document do you suggest me to prepare? A work flow diagram or a basic flowchart or another document?

I organized, analysed client needs. What is the best method for presenting analysis information back to the client?

Comment: thanks for your answer @MarvMills  I'd like to organize (interpret) client needs and present them in a diagram beside the quote document. I am specifically asking this as the matter of fact.

Comment: UML diagrams, perhaps? It's really unclear what kind of data you're trying to present, or why it belongs in a quote, or why you're including business analysis work products of any kind in a quote for services.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you should prepare a RFP (Request For Proposal) for the same including sections (but not limited to):-

1. Project Description: Write few lines about the project to start with, as introduction is required for every document
2. Project Scope of work
3. Project Timelines and Milestones: Mention here milestone of deliveries that are planned before the product go live. It would be better to represent it in a kind of Gantt Chart, which displays the Milestones and date of delivery
4. Budget: Mention here the quotation for the prices in a table format, don't use complex mathematics here and keep the table simple and readable
5. Evaluation Factors: How you reached the mentioned budget, like mention here the resources that will be involved and their pricing.
6. Point of Contact
7. Exceptions and Risks

In the scope of work section, mention the workflow diagram with blocks (not too fancy, it should look formal and professional). Client always like charts and block diagrams, as they are self explanatory, easy to understand and looks good. Don't write too much in this document, explain as many things with pictures and diagrams as you can. Use the **SmartArt** feature of Excel or Word or other tool *(for Integration and Relational description of modules)*.

Answer (score 0):

> I organized, analysed client needs. What is the best method for
>   presenting analysis information back to the client?

Based on the comments on the question, this information is going to be used to present a RFP to the client, as mentioned by Dhiman (+1!).

The key factor here as far as I can see, is to understand **who** is going to read this and **how** this analysis is going to be used. By the way, it seems you're already doing actual work, but the contract isn't firmed yet, which is a risk.

So, assuming the analysis is going to be used in a proposal, you could use any common format out there (like UML, mentioned by CG), but is vital to ensure that the *client knows how to read it*.

With that in mind, before using any format, I'd suggest to agree the format with the client before structure it. If the client understands UML, go for it. If client prefers good old PowerPoints, no problems. If prototypes are a possibility, even better. As long as you both know *how the final product will look like*.